# Inicialización por defecto en objetos globales

Tags: c++

Según tengo entendido cuando se declara un objeto, por ejemplo:

```
CuentaBancaria cuenta01;
```

Si no se inicializan los atributos en un constructor, estos, contienen valor basura. La duda es la referencia a objetos de tipo de string que valor contienen por defecto? NULL quizás? Pero esto no es valor basura.

Y si declaramos el objeto a nivel global, por ejemplo, fuera de la función `main`, entonces contendrían los atributos todos valor `0` o `NULL`? Y esto sería igual que si lo declaramos local pero `static` no?

Gracias de antemano por cualquier aclaración.

Un cordial saludo

Comment: pelaitas haz recibido muy buenas respuestas, deberias aceptar una

Answer (score 3):

> Si declaramos el objeto a nivel global, por ejemplo, fuera de la función `main`, ¿entonces contendrían los atributos todos valor `0` o `NULL`? Y esto sería igual que si lo declaramos local pero `static` ¿no?

Si, pero no por el motivo que crees. Los objetos definidos a nivel global pasan por el proceso de:

#### Inicialización estática.

Según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) la inicialización estática consiste en (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 6.6.2 Inicialización estática
>
> 1. **Las variables cuyo almacenamiento sea estático se inicializan como consecuencia de la iniciación del programa**. Las variables con almacenamiento de hilo se inicializan como consecuencia de la ejecución de un hilo. En cada una de estas fases de inicialización, la inicialización ocurre de la siguiente manera:
> 2. Un *inicializador constante* para una variable u objeto temporal `o` es un inicializador cuya expresión completa es una expresión constante, excepto si `o` es un objeto, cuyo inicializador puede invocar constructores `constexpr` para `o` y sus sub-objetos incluso si esos objetos no son clases con tipos no literales. [*Nota:* Esa clase puede tener un destructor no trivial — *fin de la nota*] **La *Inicialización constante* se aplica para la entidad. Si la inicialización constante no es aplicada, la variable con almacenamiento estático o almacenamiento de hilo es inicializada a cero**. Conjuntamente, la inicialización a cero y la inicialización constante son llamadas *inicialización estática*; cualquier otra inicialización es *inicialización dinámica*. Cualquier inicialización estática sucede antes que cualquier inicialización dinámica.

El estándar suele ser difícil de interpretar, más aún si algunos de los matices se pierden en la traducción, lo que viene a decir el texto anterior es lo siguiente:

1. Si el objeto a inicializar se encuentra en almacenamiento estático y se puede inicializar de manera constante se hará esa inicialización usando el inicializador proveído.
2. Si el objeto a inicializar se encuentra en almacenamiento estático y no se puede inicializar de manera constante se inicializará a cero.

#### En resumen.

Si tienes un objeto a nivel global y éste tiene constructor o inicializador, se usará el constructor del objeto (o el inicializador proveído) para inicializarlo. En caso contrario se inicializará a cero, vamos a comprobarlo:

```
// Carece de constructor
struct objeto { int x, y, z; };

// Es GLOBAL: Se aplica inicializacion a 0
objeto global;

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const objeto &obj)
{
    return o << '{' << obj.x << ' ' << obj.y << ' ' << obj.z << '}';
}

int main()
{
    // Es LOCAL: No se aplica ninguna inicializacion, puede contener basura.
    objeto local;
    std::cout << "Objeto local: " << local
              << "\nObjeto global: " << global;

    return 0;
}
```

La ejecución en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rY8vUuGZnYX1IOqT)</kbd> produce esta salida:

> `Objeto local: {32764 0 0}`
>
> `Objeto global: {0 0 0}`

---

> Y esto sería igual que si lo declaramos local pero `static` ¿no?

Así es, dado que es estático se aplica inicialización estática.

Answer (score 2):

> Si no se inicializan los atributos en un constructor, estos, contienen valor basura.

Los tipos nativos de C++ no disponen de ninguna inicialización por defecto. Así, este código:

```
int a;
for( ; a<10; a++ )
  std::cout << '.'; // ¿Cuantos puntos saldrán en pantalla?
```

Mostrará lo que se conoce como basura, que no es sino el valor almacenado en esa posición de memoria cuando estaba siendo utilizada por otra variable. La única forma de conseguir que estas variables tengan valores *seguros* es inicializarlas a mano:

```
for( int a=0 ; a<10; a++ )
  std::cout << '.'; // Se imprimen 10 puntos
```

Sin embargo, cuando hablamos de clases, ya sean `struct` o `class`, C++ pone a nuestra disposición los constructores. Un constructor no es más que una función que será invocada de forma automática al crear nuevos objetos. Los constructores se usan para que los nuevos objetos tengan un estado válido.

Por supuesto que se nos puede *olvidar* implementar el constructor:

```
struct Test
{
  int var;
};

Test t;
std::cout << t.var;
```

Pero en ese caso el compilador creará una implementación por defecto que lo único que hará es llamar a los constructores de los objetos anidados:

```
struct Anidado
{
  Anidado()
   : var(10)
  { std::cout << "Anidado::Anidado();\n"; }

  int var;
};

struct POO
{
  Anidado anidado;
  int var;
};

int main()
{
    POO p; // Se imprime Anidado::Anidado();
    std::cout << p.anidado.var << '\n'; // Imprime 10
    std::cout << p.var; // Imprime basura... var no tiene constructor!!!
}
```

Hay ciertas condiciones bajo las cuales el compilador no va a crear una implementación por defecto, pero ese es otro tema a tratar.

Así, con el código que has puesto en la pregunta:

```
CuentaBancaria cuenta01;
```

Lo que sucede es que el programa llamará al constructor por defecto de `CuentaBancaria`, y ya dependerá de dicho constructor que el objeto esté correctamente inicializado.

> La duda es la referencia a objetos de tipo de string que valor contienen por defecto?

La clase `std::string` es, como bien acabo de comentar, una clase, luego tiene constructor. Si tu pones lo siguiente:

```
std::string cadena;
```

Se invoca al constructor por defecto de `std::string`, el cual inicializará la memoria interna del objeto de tal manera que contenga una cadena vacía.

En cambio, una cadena al estilo C es otro cantar:

```
char* cadena;
```

En este caso hemos declarado un puntero que, al no ser una clase, **no tiene constructor**. Aquí el compilador ha creado un puntero que no apunta a ningún sitio en concreto (basura). Es por eso que los punteros hay que inicializarlos por seguridad:

```
char* cadena = nullptr; // C++11. usar 0 o NULL en versiones anteriores
```

> Y si declaramos el objeto a nivel global, por ejemplo, fuera de la función `main`, entonces contendrían los atributos todos valor `0` o `NULL`?

Dónde y cómo crees los objetos es indiferente. Todo objeto que parta de una clase acabará llamando antes o después a uno de sus constructores. Lo que si puede variar es el momento en el que se crea cada objeto... Con los objetos globales pasa que no tienes control sobre su ciclo de vida y eso puede ser peligroso... (¿qué pasa si se destruye el proveedor antes que el consumidor? ¿Y si sucede al revés?¿Es importante su orden de creación?).

Como siempre se acabará llamando a un constructor, dependerá del mismo que las variables miembro tengan un valor u otro... o que acaben teniendo basura.

> Y esto sería igual que si lo declaramos local pero `static` no?

Exacto. Lo único que variará, como ya he comentado, es el ciclo de vida de cada objeto.